# Why is my array of enumeration values null in my WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, enumeration

I have an array of enumerations on a WCF request that comes through as `null`, no matter what I have tried.
The service works apart from the issue with enumerations.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be?

**Enumeration code:**

```
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://services.myproject.com/requests/MyProject")]
    public enum Recommendation
    {
        [EnumMember]
        One = 1,
        [EnumMember]
        Two = 2,            
    }
```

**SOAP XML:**

```
 ... xmlns:lat="http://services.myproject.com/requests/MyProject" ...
 ...
 <lat:Recommendations>
        <Recommendation>One</Recommendation>
        <Recommendation>Two</Recommendation>
 </lat:Recommendations>
 ...
```

C#:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://services.myproject.com/requests/MyProject")]
public class MyRequest : Request ...
{
    //...
    [DataMember]
    public Recommendation[] Recommendations { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Currently suspect KnownType issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `[KnownType(typeof(Recommendation[]))]` attribute to your MyRequest class

Comment: Solution was to actually add [KnownType(typeof(Recommendation))]. Thanks for pointer